# Why /about-us and /about-us-amp are targeting the same page?

Tags: .htaccess, amp-html, accelerated-mobile-page

I've started working on AMP the link of my about us page is
https://www.example.com/about-us
and file name is about-us.php
in the conical i gave the link for the amp file that is
https://www.example.com/about-us-amp
and file name is about-us-amp.php

the the both links are targeting the about-us.php

Comment: Did you follow the [Linking pages with <link>](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/fundamentals/discovery#linking-pages-with-link) where you have to place in the href attribute the correct URL you want to go to.

Comment: Yes i've used the conical links in both files. I'm not sure if htaccess is creating problem or there is any thing else.

Comment: i'm not able to solve it yet! can you help?